# Admob not showing on tablet using fragments No Enough Space

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm using fragments in an Android app, in the Fragment class I'm calling admob in onViewCreated, the Admob banner shows without any problem in Smartphone when calling only one fragment, but not showing at all in the tablets when calling 2 fragments.

**EDIT:**
Just found in the logcat :
04-07 15:35:37.373: W/Ads(1380): Not enough space to show ad. Needs 1024x50 dp, but only has 340x471 dp.

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        // TODO: load ads
        mAdView = (AdView) getView().findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
```

In the fragment XML layout file, I've added the admob AdView :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="@android:color/white" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        app:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        app:adUnitId="@string/admob_banner_ad_unit_id" >
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the layout file for sw720p calling 2 fragments:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <fragment android:name="com.recipes.app.RecipesListFragment"
              android:id="@+id/list_fragment"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" 
              android:layout_marginRight="2dp"/>

    <fragment android:name="com.recipes.app.DetailFragment"
              android:id="@+id/detail_fragment"
              android:layout_weight="2"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Make sure you do test adverts, real adverts may not always be served up in good time causing you to think it's not working. Plus admob don't like you testing with real adverts.

Comment: It seems its a size problem, this is the message shown in logcat : 04-07 15:35:37.373: W/Ads(1380): Not enough space to show ad. Needs 1024x50 dp, but only has 340x471 dp.

Comment: I guess the advert should be given full width, but if is within one of those fragments it won't have full width, just 1/3rd or 2/3rds. Maybe you should overlay the advert in a separate fragment or directly in the layouts.